# Uso de "en al frente"

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Necesito una segunda opinión sobre la frase *en al frente* en la siguiente oración.

> *La lección estadística empieza con los estudiantes escribiendo sus nombres en notas adhesivas y fijándolas en el tablero en al frente del salón*

Me parece ser un poco torpe. Usualmente se usa *en el frente*.

---

I need a second opinion on the phrase *en al frente* in the following sentence.

> *La lección estadística empieza con los estudiantes escribiendo sus nombres en notas adhesivas y fijándolas en el tablero en al frente del salón*

That phrase seems a little clumsy. Usually *en el frente* is used instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it seems like a bad translation to me because `en al frente` is not a valid expression, as you say `en el frente` is valid, and I'd rather use `al frente` or even `que esta al frente`, so I like these options better:

- fijándolas en el tablero al frente del salón
- fijándolas en el tablero en el frente del salón
- fijándolas en el tablero que está al frente del salón
- fijándolas en el tablero en la parte delantera del salón

Also just FYI, as you mentioned it's important to note that considering the context of your phrase, the intended meaning for `salón` here is `aula` which [according to rae](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=qsiFMH4znDXX2ZdcG3mc%7CJGwnBnDy0DXX2XkXtvdT) seems to be specifically a latin american use for the word.

Comment: ¿Qué parte de México es de Usted?

Comment: @Dombey I'm from [Chihuahua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chihuahua_(state)). Also just for the sake of Spanish improvement, one of the `de` is misplaced, the question should be `¿De qué parte de México es Usted?` (otherwise it'd imply I own a part of México)

Comment: ¡Gracías por la correción!

Answer (score 2):

No solo la expresión *en al frente* es incorrecta (las preposiciones *en* y *a* nunca van seguidas), sino que, sinceramente, no sé qué puede querer decir. Nunca he oído hablar de *el frente* de un salón. Podría ser *el frontal* de un salón, pero normalmente *el frontal* se encuentra en el exterior (por ejemplo, en la fachada), no en el interior. Además, el lugar habitual para dar una lección no es un *salón*, sino un *aula*. Aun sin conocer el significado que se quiere dar a la frase, ofrezco algunas alternativa:

- fijándolas en el tablero que hay en el frontal del aula
- fijándolas en el tablero que hay al fondo del aula
- fijándolas en el tablero que hay a la entrada del aula

Comment: Interesante, debe ser alguna diferencia regional puesto que `el frente` de un salón es una expresión conocida y usada en México, mientras que nunca oí hablar de `el frontal`

Comment: En ese caso, se trata de una diferencia regional, sin duda. Por cierto, @darkajax, ¿qué es *el frente de un salón* en México?

Comment: *el frente de un salón* es la parte delantera sin una distincion especifica, usualmente enfrente de los estudiantes y es donde suele encontrarse el profesor o profesora, además de la pizarra

Comment: @Gorpik Sí, es una diferencia regional. La definición de 'salón" dada por la Real Academia Española en su sitio dice 'aula' y es usada en México y algunos paises latinoamericas. El sitio es aquí: http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=sal%C3%B3n

Comment: En ese caso, está claro que se trata de una simple errata en el texto original. Con sustituir *al* por *el*, ya queda correcto, como apunta @darkajax en su respuesta.